# Azure Function blobTrigger not registered

Tags: azure, azure-functions

As title, when I try to run my nodejs based azure function, I come across the following error:

```
The following 1 functions are in error: [7/2/19 1:41:17 AM] ***: The binding type(s) 'blobTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.
```

I tried `func extensions install --force` with no luck still, any idea? My development environment is macOS and I tried both nodejs based `azure-functions-core-tools` and brew based install both doesn't work.

The most scary part is this used to work fine on the same machine, all a sudden it just failed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can refer to the offical tutorial for Linux [`Create your first function hosted on Linux using Core Tools and the Azure CLI (preview)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli-linux) to start up your work.

Due to the same shell `bash` used in MacOS and Linux, I will start up my sample demo for you on Linux and avoid using those incompatible operations. First of all, assumed that there is an usable NodeJS runtime in your environment. The version of node and npm is `v10.16.0` and `6.9.0`.

1. To install `azure-functions-core-tools` via `npm` and inspect it, as the figure below.

   [image]
2. Next to init a project `MyFunctionProj` via `func`

   [image]
3. Then to new a function with blob trigger

   [image]

   There is an issue about the requirement for .NET Core SDK. So I move to https://www.microsoft.com/net/download to install it, here is incompatible with MacOS, but I think you can easy to fix it by yourself. So I followed the offical installation instruction to install it.

   [image]
4. After installed .NET Core SDK, try to `func new` again.

   [image]

   And completed like this.

   [image]
5. To change two configuration files `MyFunctionProj/local.settings.json` and `MyFunctionProj/MyBlobTrigger/function.json`, as below.

   ## MyFunctionProj/local.settings.json

   ```
   {
     "IsEncrypted": false,
     "Values": {
       "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
       "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<your real storage connection string like `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<your account name>;AccountKey=<your account key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net`"
     }
   }
   ```

   ## MyFunctionProj/MyBlobTrigger/function.json

   ```
   {
     "bindings": [
       {
         "name": "myBlob",
         "type": "blobTrigger",
         "direction": "in",
         "path": "<the container name you want to monitor>/{name}",                                                                                                  
         "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
6. Then, command `func host start --build` to start up it without any error.

   [image]

   Let's upload a test file named `test.txt` via Azure Storage Explorer to the container `<the container name you want to monitor>` which be configured in the `function.json` file. And you will see that `MyBlobTrigger` has been triggered and work fine.

   [image]

Hope it helps.